# Convert "20120821203354" (non-delimited timestamp) to "2012-08-21 20:33" in a shell?

Tags: regex, bash, time

I want to take `/home/deploy/releases/20120821203354`

and return:

```
2012-08-21 20:33
```

Basically take the stuff after `'releases/'` and split based on the position of the numbers.

Background: OS X 10.7; will be used in bash script.

```
/embarrassed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OSX, in bash, you can use the `date` command as you would in FreeBSD.

```
$ text="/home/deploy/releases/20120821203354"
$ date -j -f "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" "${text##*/}" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
2012-08-21 20:33
```

Note that the options for `date` in BSD operating systems are different than they would be in Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Here you are.

```
a=/home/deploy/releases/20120821203354                                          
b=${a#/home/deploy/releases/}                                                   
c="${b:0:4}-${b:4:2}-${b:6:2} ${b:8:2}:${b:10:2}"
```

It's all about [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: More generally, you can use: `b=${a##*/}` to remove the longest string ending with a slash, which is equivalent to the venerable `b=$(basename $a)` that I'd use almost automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adapt this to your needs:

```
echo " /home/deploy/releases/20120821203354" | awk -F/ '{print $5}' | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)"-"substr($0,5,2)"-"substr($0,7,2)" "substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)}'
```